# Using sizeof() on an array passed to a function

Tags: c, arrays, function, pic32

I have a quick question about the C sizeof() function.  I'm passing an array into a function, and inside that function, I want to check the size of the array.  However, regardless of the size of the input array, inside the function, it always seems to have a size of 4.  For example:

```
void checkArraySize(char data[])
{
    int internalSize = sizeof(data); //internalSize is reported as 4
}

void main(void)
{
    char data[] = {0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05, 0x06, 0x07, 0x08};
    int externalSize = sizeof(data); //externalSize is reported as 8

    checkArraySize(data);                                             
}
```

As the comments in the code state, before I call a function like checkArraySize(), I check the size of the array, and it shows 8.  However, when I check the size of the array inside the function, it only reports as having 4 elements (it reports 4 elements regardless of the size of the input array).

More often than not, when I see issues like this, it's because there is a gap in my understanding of the topic.  So, I'm sure I'm just missing something with how passing arrays works.  If not, any ideas as to why this is happening?

Note: This is on a PIC32, so I'm using Microchip's MPLAB X IDE and XC32 compiler.

Comment: BTW: `sizeof` is not a function, but an operator. That's why you can use it on types (use parentheses) and expressions (no need for parentheses). The argument is not evaluated, unless it's a variably modified type, and thus the result is a compile-time constant expression. (If you hadn't said you are on an embedded system, I would have advised you that `main` always returns `int`. Things are more diverse in freestanding environments though.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Array in C always passed by reference. Thats why you are getting pointer size each time, not actual size.

To work with array in C as an argument, you should pass size of array with array.

I modified your program to working condition:

```
typedef unsigned char BYTE;

void checkArraySize(BYTE data[], int sizeOfArray)
{
    int internalSize = sizeOfArray;   
    printf("%d", internalSize );                  
}

void main(void)
{
    BYTE data[] = {0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05, 0x06, 0x07, 0x08};
    int externalSize = sizeof(data)/sizeof(BYTE);                   //it would return number of elements in array

    checkArraySize(data, externalSize);                                             
}
```

passed by reference means only address of first element of array is sent. If you change anything even inside function **checkArraySize**, this change would be reflected to original array too. Check modified above example.

```
typedef unsigned char BYTE;

void checkArraySize(BYTE data[])
{
    int internalSize = sizeof(data);   
    printf("%d\n", internalSize );     
    data[3]=  0x02;             //internalSize is reported as 4
}

void main(void)
{
    BYTE data[] = {0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05, 0x06, 0x07, 0x08};
    int externalSize = sizeof(data);                   //externalSize is reported as 8
    printf("Value before calling function: 0x%x\n",data[3]);
    checkArraySize(data);  
    printf("Value after calling function: 0x%x\n",data[3]);
}
```

output would be:

```
Value before calling function: 0x4
4
Value after calling function: 0x2
```

Comment: passed by reference?

Comment: @tristan passed by reference is here only address of first element of array is sent. If you change anything even inside function **checkArraySize**, this change would be reflected to original array too. I added example in answer.

Comment: C doesn't have 'reference'.  it's array decaying to pointer i think.

Answer (score 7):

```
void checkArraySize(char data[])
```

will be translated to

```
void checkArraySize(char* data)
```

So, the code calculates the size of a pointer.
4 is the pointer size in your computer.
In a 64-bit system, it will output 8.

Answer (score 1):

Arrays are not copyable things in C and C++. Therefore inventors of thesele languages were forced to add somę non-intuitive automatic Type conversion from array to pointer onto their first element in order to offer programmer a way to pass array as argument to function.

Using sizeof operator (not a function) on such argument returns size of pointer Type rather than data size.

**extra cents**
sizeof operator is expanded during compilation rather run time. From the other side passed Arrays to a function could have different sizes. So casting such Arrays to pointers has another one explanation: sizeof couldnt resolve size of different Arrays during compile time.