# c++ memset() works different in/out of the main function

Tags: c++, c

I got a problem with the memset funciton
Here is part of the code
Code1

```
int main()
{
    long long int num=600851475143;
    bool factor[5000];
    //memset(factor,true,sizeof(factor));
    primer_factor_find(factor);
    int largest=largest_primer_factor(num,factor);
    cout<<largest<<endl;  
    return 0;
}

void primer_factor_find(bool factor[])
{
    memset(factor,true,sizeof(factor));
    int j,k;
    for(j=1;j<=2500;j++)
        for(k=3*j+1;k<=5000;k+=(2*j+1))
            factor[k]=false;
}
```

the only difference between Code2 is the location of the memset function.(In Code2,memset is in the main)
I find Code1 doesn't work at all.Code2 works fine.What's the matter?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5493281/c-sizeof-a-passed-array

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27096272/using-sizeof-on-an-array-passed-to-a-function

Comment: Also note that `memset()` really operates at the byte level, but `bool` is not the same thing.  You could use `std::fill()` instead, which will result in similar code, but is safer.

Comment: i think in order to work memset properly in your function "primer_factor_find" you need to mention size of the array explicitely. Because  sizeof(factor) will return size of pointer.

Comment: According to this Meta discussion:  http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/266246/578749 this question shouldn't be marked as duplicate. The causes of the problem are the same, but the question and perceived symptoms are different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
void primer_factor_find(bool factor[])
{
    memset(factor,true,sizeof(factor));
```

passing unbounded array into function basically equal to pointer. At this point, `sizeof` give you the pointer size, and leave most of the content garbage.

Whereas you put that to main, the compiler knows the full size.

Answer (score 1):

In the function signature the array is converted to a pointer `bool *`, and so `sizeof factor` will return `sizeof(bool *)`.

Comment: Can we please find one of the infinite dupes instead of providing an answer

Answer (score 1):

`factor` decays to a pointer here `void primer_factor_find(bool factor[])`

Arrays decays to pointers when they are passed to a function.